# Python3 no module named tld

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando usar o tld https://pypi.org/project/tld/ e não to conseguindo usar ele no python3, só no python 2.7, o que não convém pra mim, já que todo o meu projeto está em python3. Na documentação diz que é compatível com o python3.5 que é o que estou usando. Qual poderia ser o problema?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sufixo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tld import get_tld
ImportError: No module named 'tld'
```

Comment: É possível que o primeiro `pip` em seu PATH seja o `pip` do 2.7. Se esse for o caso, então fazer `pip install xyz` sempre vai instalar só pro Python 2.7. Experimente rodar `python3 -m pip install tld` e veja se funciona.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Tente usar o comando pip install tld no powershell ou terminal. Funciona perfeitamente com python 3 instalado com anaconda.

Comment: Tenta: `pip3 install tld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como é a versão do `python3` você deve usar o seguinte comando:

```bsh
$ python3 -m pip install tld
```